# Best pratice for network call in android app

Tags: android

I am building an app in which there are frequent network calls. Often, I find myself waiting for the response from the server while I am using 3g internet connection. Data size isn't big but don't understand why it takes so long to fetch small data.

I am using volley library. Should I use AsyncTask ? or Should I use RestClient and make network calls by starting a new thread ?

Please help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using volley, it already has a thread pool and delivers the response to ui thread. Maybe you should check your servers response time or network latencies

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) in the official android developer site about how to perform network operations/calls.

> I am using volley library. Should I use AsyncTask ? or Should I use
>   RestClient and make network calls by starting a new thread ?

As wrecker said:

> Volley already has a thread pool and delivers the response to ui
>   thread.

About the RestClient, you didn't mention your server exposes a REST API, in case it does, [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) can help you to achive what you want in a non-ui thread.